# ZF3 redirect()->toUrl() not redirecting

Tags: redirect, zend-framework3, zend-route

I'm having a weird issue with ZF3.
I have a vanilla form in the view and a jquery ajax to send it to the controller, something like this:

```
<form>some form</form>
<script>
    $("#form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "stats",
            data: {name: 'TEST'} // name selected in the form
        });
    });
</script>
```

The controller for action stats looks like this:

```
$stat = new Stat();

$route_name = $this->params()->fromRoute('name', 'none');
$post_name = $this->params()->fromPost('name', 'none');

if(!strcmp($route_name, 'none')) // if no redirection yet
{
    if(!strcmp($post_name, 'none')) // if no form was sent
    {
        // display the form to choose the customer
        return new ViewModel([
            'customer_list' => $stat->get_customer_list(),
        ]);
    }
    else // if the form was sent, get name and direct to /stats/someName
    {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('stats', ['name' => 'someName']);
    }
}
else // after redirection, get the name in the URL and show some data about this customer
{
    return new ViewModel([
        'avg_time' => $stat->get_avg_time(rawurldecode($route_name)),
    ]);
}
```

The problem is that the redirection does not occure on the screen but I still get the route parameter if I print `$route_name` after submitting the form.

Anyway, the goal is to have a form with a select to choose the customer name and load the customer data into `/stats/[name]`. Am I going in the wrong direction ? And is the redirection issue a bug or my code is wrong ?

Comment: You're doing an asynchronous request and are expecting the response to behave like a synchronous request. If you would print the response of the jQuery AJAX request into the browser's console, you'd see it working as expected. If you want stuff to be done based on data send from the form and you want a page refresh (e.g. redirect) to occur, just let the browser handle the form sending. Update the form action attribute with the "stats" url (`<form action="/stats">`) and remove/disable the JS that does the same.

Comment: @rkeet alright, made it with post and action="stats/view_customer", it works.
Is there any way I can get "stats/[name of customer]" ?

Comment: Solved it, I change the action to the value of select using Jquery on submit. Thanks

Comment: Well done. Would be good if you posted how you fixed it in the end. You can then later accept your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there I solved it thx to `rkeet`, this is the form & jquery:

```
<form id="customer_choice" method="POST" action=""> some form </form>
<script>
    $("#customer_choice").submit(function () {
        $("#customer_choice").attr('action', 'stats/' + $("#customer_select").val())
    });
</script>
```

And this is the controller (hope no customer is named 'none'):

```
$stat = new Stat();

$name = $this->params()->fromRoute('name', 'none');

if(!strcmp($name, 'none'))
{
    return new ViewModel([
        'customer_list' => $stat->get_customer_list(),
    ]);
}
else
{
    return new ViewModel([
        'avg_time' => $stat->get_avg_time($name),
    ]);
}
```

The result is `basepath/stats/[customer name]` and changing the url manually works as well.

(if you don't want changing the url manually to change the result, use fromPost instead of fromRoute)